# Finding all possible values of a,b,c,x,y,z in given interval, such that a^x+b^y=c^z

Tags: c#, optimization, console-application

I want to make C# program for finding combinations of positive integers a,b,c,x,y,z in given interval such that a^x+b^y=c^z. Variables a,b,c must be in interval [abc_min,abc_max] and x,y,z must be in interval [xyz_min,xyz_max]. I tried using six for loops, but it is very slow. Is there a better code to find all combinations in very big interval (for example [0,100]) for a short time? This is my code, but it is very slow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int abc_min = 3, abc_max = 10, xyz_min = 3, xyz_max = 20, num = 0;
            int a, b, c, x, y, z;
            BigInteger p1, p2, p3;
            for (a = abc_min; a <= abc_max; a++)
            {
                for (b = abc_min; b <= abc_max; b++)
                {
                    for (c = abc_min; c <= abc_max; c++)
                    {
                        for (x = xyz_min; x <= xyz_max; x++)
                        {
                            for (y = xyz_min; y <= xyz_max; y++)
                            {
                                for (z = xyz_min; z <= xyz_max; z++)
                                {
                                    p1 = BigInteger.Pow(a, x);
                                    p2 = BigInteger.Pow(b, y);
                                    p3 = BigInteger.Pow(c, z);
                                    if (p1 + p2 == p3)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("{0}^{1}+{2}^{3}={4}^{5}\n", a, x, b, y, c, z);
                                        num += 1;                                            
                                        Console.ReadKey();
                                        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------\n");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} instances found.", num);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError occured.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're producing every permutation instead of every combination.

Comment: since all numbers are positives, you should loop on c and z, and whenever the left part of equation is > to c^z , you can ignore all greater (a,x,b,y) this should cut quite some time.

Comment: Seems like generic algorithmic problem, nothing C# specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initially calculate an array of all `a` values in power of `x` for the given intervals:

```
BigInteger[,] abcPow = new BigInteger[abc_max - abc_min + 1, xyz_max - xyz_min + 1];
for (a = abc_min; a <= abc_max; a++)
    for (x = xyz_min; x <= xyz_max; x++)
        abcPow[a - abc_min, x - xyz_min] = BigInteger.Pow(a, x);
```

Then you don't need to calculate `BigInteger.Pow` on each iteration:

```
for (a = abc_min; a <= abc_max; a++)
{
    for (b = a; b <= abc_max; b++)
    {
        for (c = abc_min; c <= abc_max; c++)
        {
            for (x = xyz_min; x <= xyz_max; x++)
            {
                p1 = abcPow[a - abc_min, x - xyz_min];
                for (y = xyz_min; y <= xyz_max; y++)
                {
                    p2 = abcPow[b - abc_min, y - xyz_min];
                    for (z = xyz_min; z <= xyz_max; z++)
                    {
                        p3 = abcPow[c - abc_min, z - xyz_min];
                        if (p1 + p2 == p3)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}^{1}+{2}^{3}={4}^{5}\n", a, x, b, y, c, z);
                            num++;
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------\n");
                            if (a != b)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}^{1}+{2}^{3}={4}^{5}\n", b, y, a, x, c, z);
                                num++;
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else if (p1 + p2 < p3)
                        {
                            // No more solutions could be found for the given z
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Pay attention that `p1 = ...` and `p2 = ...` moved out of the inner loop, because they don't depend on the inner loop's variable.*

**EDIT**
Since `a^x + b^y = b^y + a^x`, it makes sense to start `b` loop from `a`, and when the solution is found and if `a != b`, output two solutions.

On my machine it speeded up the calculation in `~20` times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea..

First, define classes that look like such (this is all paraphrased C#, may require refactoring):

```
class Exponential
{
    public int base;
    public int power;
}

class ExponentialResult : List<Exponential>
{
    private BigInteger result;

    public ExponentialResult(BigInteger value)
    {
        result = value;
    }

    public BigInteger Result
    {
        get { return result; }
    }
}

public BigIntegerComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(BigIntegerComparer x, BigIntegerComparer y)
    {
        return (int) BigInteger.Subtract(x, y);
    }
}
```

Then, you'll want to accumulate all values of the form (base^power) into `Exponential` objects using something like the following

```
public Dictionary<BigInteger, ExponentialResult> AccumulateRange(int base_min, int base_max, int power_min, int power_max)
{
    Dictionary<BigInteger, ExponentialResult> dictionary = new Dictionary<BigInteger, ExponentialResult>();
    for (int base = base_min; base <= base_max; ++base)
    {
        for(int power = power_min; power <= power_max; ++power)
        {
            Exponential exp = new Exponential();
            exp.base = base;
            exp.power = power;

            BigInteger result = BigInteger.Pow(base, power);
            ExponentialResult set;
            if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(result, out set))
            {
               set = new ExponentialResult(result);
               dictionary.Add(result, set);
            }
            set.Add(exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the entire set of values from the range specified, you'll then want to sort them and iterate over them properly, and check additions and what not:

```
public void Calculate(IDictionary<BigInteger, ExponentialResult> dictionary)
{
    SortedList<BigInteger, ExponentialResult> list = new SortedList<BigInteger, ExponentialResult>(dictionary, new BigIntegerComparer());

    foreach (KeyValuePair<BigInteger, ExponentialResult> kv1 in list)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<BigInteger, ExponentialResult> kv2 in list)
        {
            ExponentialResult sum;
            if (list.TryGetValue(BigInteger.Add(kv1.Key, kv2.Key), out sum))
            {
               //we have found one such that a^x + b^y = c^z
            }

            if (kv1 == kv2)
            {
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the inside of that `if`, where the comment is, accumulate a set of results such that all the pairs stored in `ExponentialResult kv1.Value`, combined with all the pairs stored in `ExponentialResult kv2.Value`, result in all the pairs stored in `ExponentialResult sum`.